# Apache Mod Filter AH02429

Tags: apache, mod-filter

After a fresh install of Apache 2.4.27 on my Unix system I discovered something really odd. My local server giving me 500 error with this error log 
`AH02429: Response header name 'Content-Length' contains invalid characters, aborting request` I tried with all installed browser `Chrome`, `Firefox`, `Safari` problem is same. As I can see my browsers not sending this header, not sure why I am encountering this error. I tried with curl and it's same. Added some tweaks on my httpd.conf file, nothing changed.

I Googled and found that this error comes form apache new module `Filter`. My apache complied with all modules is there anyway to tell the Filter module to not check for headers or something?

Any kind of help will be life saving.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I used `HttpProtocolOptions Unsafe` but it's same :(